# Dual Monitors with ESXi 6

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have ESXi 6 running on a server (another PC which is a test) and I have various VMs there of the Linux and Windows variety.

I would like the VMs to use 2 or 3 of my monitors when accessing them - I'm currently using the vSphere client.

I have seen that some people use RDP to access the Windows machines but

(a) What about my Linux VMs

(b) I imagine this wouldn't be possible when they are configured to host only (no outward network interface connection)

I have tried changed the video card settings, auto-detect and specifying the amount of monitors and increasing the RAM but to no avail.

The reason I want this set up is to have various infrastructures and different specialized machines (for example, malware analysis) to play with.

Comment: it is for work purposes - replicating the environment at home

Answer (score 4):

ESXi is a bare metal hypervisor. It is designed for headless use, and is more of an enterprise environment product. For the example you have given it would be more suitable to use VMware Workstation [VMware Product Website](http://www.vmware.com/uk/products/workstation)

You can then use dual monitors, and it is OS agnostic.

Comment: ESXi should be able to virtualize multiple displays, but the console won't show them. You would need remote access software like RDP or VNC.  Although, the graphics on a non-VDI ESXi host are probably not very good. Might as well use Workstation.

Comment: But even within an enterprise I image the VMs need to be accessed?

Comment: The problem with workstation (I already have it on my current PC) is that I need to run it on top of an OS; I'm never going to use the OS so it is just eating unnecessary resources. This combined with all the VMs are grouped together (visually bad to look at) makes it, in my humble opinion, a poor choice.   ESXi is my ideal solution but the fact that multiple displays doesn't seem to be possible is a real downer

Comment: This is all wrong. You're using the incorrect tool, have the wrong application in mind and should reassess your needs.

Comment: I don't believe there is a tool out there which meets my needs - remote connection, small footprint on the server and multiple display capability.............  Both ESXi and Workstation fail to meet my 3 requirements in some way

Comment: @JohnMahowald  Could I use the horizon view client?